# Is there a way that I can have more OSX styles quick launch bar in Ubuntu 15?

Tags: 15.04, taskbar

Is there a way that I can have more OSX styles quick launch bar in Ubuntu 15? Or at placed on the bottom with left and right margins?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Although your question is a good one, it does not seem to have enough information for us to be able to help you. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/747071/edit) your question, and attempt to clarify what you would like to change about your utility bar in Ubuntu. Also when editing please specify version ex. (15.04, 15.10)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few OS X Dock clones for Ubuntu, but no real themes for the built-in launcher. It's also nearly impossible to change it position. Auto-hiding the Unity Launcher and installing an alternative will be easier. Here are some third-party dock utilities with an OS X style.

I personally think Docky is the best launcher alternative. It has a bunch of themes, can be placed on any side of the screen, and even supports multiple docks at once. It's highly customizable. Website: http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki
Install it by running `sudo apt-get install docky` in a terminal.

Another nice alternative is Cairo Dock. I haven't used this one very much, or very recently, but I remember it being stable and simple. Wesbsite: http://glx-dock.org/
Install it by running `sudo apt-get install cairo-dock`

There are probably quite a few others, but these are the ones I know about, and the ones that work pretty well.

Comment: I also notice that you are on 15.04. 15.04 reached its end-of-life date on February 4th. You should consider upgrading to 15.10.